# webpack autoprefixer load browserslistrc

Tags: webpack, autoprefixer

I would like use `.browserslistrc` file for load my browsers config with webpack (css-loader create conflict with -webkit-flexbox prefix.

So, i've create my `.browserslistrc` file and test with my `package.json`, but my config isn't load :

```
# Browsers that we support

Last 10 versions
```

My package.json  :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.13.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.14.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.24.0",
    "css-mqpacker": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint": "^3.18.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.3",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^1.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.5.0"
},
```

Anyone have already add .browserslistrc file on webpack config ?

Answer (score 1):

I switched to `"autoprefixer": "^7.1.1"` in my `package.json` and used the inline `require` form in my Webpack config (1.x):

```
...

postcss() {
  return [
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ];
},
```

the `.browserslistrc` was picked correctly.

Before, on version `6.x`,  I had to specify it manually in my webpack config file for `autoprefixer`, the file was not picked correctly:

```
autoprefixer({
  browsers: [
    '>1%',
    'last 4 versions',
    'Firefox ESR',
    'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
  ]
}),
```

I think also the `browsers` option in `package.json` would have worked but I never tested that.